# Compare UNIXTIME in PHP from MySQL and now

Tags: php, mysql

I'm getting a UNIXTIME stamp from MySQL and I would really like to compare it to now, and see how much time is in between the two; as in xx sec ago.

I'm not at all sure to even look, simple Google search help me nowhere.

A push into the right direction would be really appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

You can get the current unix timestamp (which are the number of seconds since 0:00:00 1970-01-01 GMT) in PHP using [`time()`](http://php.net/manual/function.time.php).

Comparison can be done using simple substraction, where `$mysqltimestamp`is the timestamp from MySQL.

```
$elapsedTimeInSeconds = abs($mysqltimestamp - time());
```

Besides using PHP you can also directly calculate the difference in the MySQL database (see http://dev.mysql.com/doc/en/date-and-time-functions.html), this also prevents possible timezone issues.

```
select (timestampcol - UNIX_TIMESTAMP()) as timetiff FROM yourtable
```

Comment: This is a bad practice.

Comment: @VasilShaddix Better approach?

Answer (score 0):

use `time()`

http://php.net/manual/en/function.time.php

This method in php returns the current time, also as an UNIX-Timestamp.

With the following code you could get the seconds between now and the time from the database:

```
$time = time();
$difference = $time - $database_time;
```

Comment: This is a bad practice.

Answer (score 0):

A good practice is not to compare php time to mysql time.

If you are going to work with a mysql time, you should make one more query for the current timestamp in the mysql server and then do something like:

`$diff = $mysqlCurrentTimestamp - $mysqlTimestamp;`

Your mysql server can be in a different timezone then your php server. It's better to work only with the time from the php, because it's easier to manipulate.

Comment: The unix timestamp should be independant to timezones since it counts the nuimber of seconds since 0:00:00 1970-01-01 GMT

Comment: Depends how you create the timestamp, if you have a datetime col and you want a timestamp from it, then you have no idea in the mysql server what is going on.

Comment: UNIX-Timestamp is defined as GMT-Timezone. There is no difference, except someone implemented something very, very wrong.